# How to set no routing order in docusign recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP API and I want my recipient to sign without any routing order, meaning whoever access first gets to sign first.

Is this possible?

I changed my routing order to all 1. It prompts me to add the signature tab.

FYI, I am creating a signature tab not via templates ( I have configured the same roles with my templates) as I am using one form to generate multiple signatures and it is working. I just need to make the routing order to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

A routing order must be specified in the DocuSign workflow prior to sending out the envelope. From what you describe though, I would recommend looking into the new Signing Groups feature: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/using-signing-groups.htm.